# How can I analyse Mathematica data using Wolfram|Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

How can I analyse data stored in *Mathematica* using Wolfram | Alpha? Here is an example:

I have a list: `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

I can plot it in *Mathematica*, like this:

[image]

But once I try to use Wolfram | Alpha, an error message appears:

[image]

How can I perform different types of analyses on *Mathematica* data using Wolfram | Alpha?

Comment: Try `= List plot of {1,2,3,4,5}`

Comment: I edited your question quite heavily to make it more clear, and to correct the grammar.  Please verify that it is still asking what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific example, the following does what you want:

```
= List plot of {1,2,3,4,5}
```

But in general don't send *WolframAlpha* inputs as though you're using *Mathematica*. Just send free-form linguistic input i.e. plain English (or other languages it understands). For example, to plot the Sine function don't type `Plot[Sin[x],{x,-3,3}]`

just type "plot sin of x from -3 to 3"

Interestingly, if you send the following `= a + 2` to *WolframAlpha*, it returns the correct result, adding 2 to each element of a. But using a in place of the list in the free-form input seems to confuse *WolframAlpha*.

Comment: I think the gist of the question is: how can we transfer data present in Mathematica to Wolfram|Alpha? That is, use the variable a directly. (I don't think it's directly possible, at least not without W|A Pro (??))

Comment: @Szabolcs see my edit above. It works partially.

Comment: Interesting observation, and +1 for that!

Comment: It seems W|A is very quirky: if you give the list a longer name, it'll recognize it: `mylist = {1, 2, 4, 8, 20}`, `= plot mylist`.  But the plot won't exactly be what you'd expect ...

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes you're right, that's what I meant by W|A being confused. I got a plot of `x^2` instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs and Runny - When you type `=a+2` into Mathematica, it sends it WolframAlpha, interprets it, and (if possible) returns a simple Mathematica expression to generate the result. You can do this whether `a` is defined in your mathematica session or not.  If a *is* defined, then it will evaluate as normal once back in your Mathematica session.  But `a` was always just "a" as far as WolframAlpha was concerned.

Comment: @Mark What has always bothered me about W|A is that it doesn't have a reliable syntax. Sometimes it's difficult to guess the right input to get it what I want ... like in this `mylist` example. The name of the variable influences the result. One other simple example I always wanted to get working but could never figure out is to list countries ordered by annual births per population.  It has the data, but the natural language interface seems to make it impossible to get it to do the division (births/population) *and* the ordering at the same time.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not sure that W|A has syntax at all - let alone "reliable syntax". :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure: I don't think what you say about `a` only being evaluated in your Mathematica session is true: depending on your preference settings ("Internet Connectivity" -> "Wolfram Alpha Settings") there is "session data" sent to the WoframAlpha servers  -- and that includes the values of global variables, as can be seen from the "Session Information" dialog that pops up when you set "Mathematica Session Info" to "Ask before sending". As for the syntax issue, I think this is by design: "Free-form natural language input" looks pretty much like the opposite of "reliable syntax" :-)

Comment: @AlbertRetey Of course, you're absolutely correct that you can *generally* send session info from Mathematica to W|A via the `WolframAlpha` commands. My claim is very specific to the input "plot a". The reason is that "plot a" has it's own valid interpretation and this is what the computational code ultimately sees. More examples might illuminate but, obviously, this is taking us a bit far afield from the original question.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: My point was that the `WolframAlpha` commands _generally_ send session data, but it's up to the servers interpretation of the free form input whether it makes use of that data. For the `a+2` and `plot a` cases it indeed looks like it doesn't make use of the session data and your interpretation of what happens seems correct. The session data dialog indicates that the value of `a` is actually sent to the server, but then is ignored. Anyway, I fully agree that this is taking us far away from the original question...